# How to write data in a csv file within single-page-application(React JS )?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, papaparse

I want to write or overwrite data(or insert row) in a csv file within react-application(create-react-app) . 
My App.js file for now is -

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';

const csvData =[
  ['Ahmed', 'Tomi' , 'ah@smthing.co.com'] ,
  ['Raed', 'Labes' , 'rl@smthing.co.com'] ,
  ['Yezzi','Min l3b', 'ymin@cocococo.com']
];

export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
            </div>
            );
    }

}
```

Here , I want to insert csvData in a csv file called data.csv within my react-application

my data.csv for now is :

```
Name,NickName,Email
Rahul B.,Rah,bbh@smthing.co.com
Abhinav K.,Abhi,xyzh@smthing.co.com
Akshay G.,Aksh,abc@smthing.co.com
```

where

```
Name,NickName,Email
```

are headers of my csv file .

I want my data.csv to look like -

```
Name,NickName,Email
Rahul B.,Rah,bbh@smthing.co.com
Abhinav K.,Abhi,xyzh@smthing.co.com
Akshay G.,Aksh,abc@smthing.co.com
Ahmed, Tomi , ah@smthing.co.com
Raed, Labes , rl@smthing.co.com
Yezzi,Min l3b,ymin@cocococo.com
```

So how to update data.csv with my App component (React component) .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you mean on the users file system? The browser does not have access to the users file system because that would be a massive breach of security. If you want to generate a CSV file and make it available for download you will need to do it server-side.

Comment: I want it within my project-structure  i.e I have already created a csv file within my project structure with the location of the directory known . Is that possible ? @AnthonyManning-Franklin

Comment: If your react application is running in a web browser then it cannot access the file system. If it were a native desktop application, i.e. React running in Electron, then it _could_ access the file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this library 
which was helpful to me

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv

Please note this command will install the library in your project folder.

```
npm i react-csv
```

```js
import {CSVLink, CSVDownload} from 'react-csv';

const csvData =[
  ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'] ,
  ['Ahmed', 'Tomi' , 'ah@smthing.co.com'] ,
  ['Raed', 'Labes' , 'rl@smthing.co.com'] ,
  ['Yezzi','Min l3b', 'ymin@cocococo.com']
];
```

```xml
<CSVLink data={csvData} >Download me</CSVLink>
// or
<CSVDownload data={csvData} target="_blank" />
```